# Playing a sound with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, wav

I have a link in my html. Like this:

```
<a href="#" class="sound">Click</a>
```

When you click on this button. Then a sound will play. But how can i make that with javascript / jquery. This is the sound:

[Sound](http://staging.newdayatwork.com/wp-content/themes/roots/static/wav/Bliep%20Hoog%201%20rev%20k.wav)

Comment: Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp) out

Comment: take a look at http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

Comment: You should never refer to w3c schools . See http://www.w3fools.com

Comment: @harsha And you shouldn't refer to w3fools.com on SO without providing an alternative link, it's just noise otherwise. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120621/w3fools-alternatives

Answer (score 0):

The best practice cross-browser wise, would probably be using flash. However if you want to use the nifty HTML5 solutions, you could have a look at this place:

http://code.coneybeare.net/getting-html5-audio-tag-and-flash-fallback-to